# List of URL to be placed in XML TAGS iteratively

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file. I have many urls in the form of list of String in c#. I want those urls in crawled URLS to be placed in xml child tag of loc by iteration. Please help me.

```
List<string> crawledUrls = new List<string>();  // List of  included URLS in c#

public void xmlfile()
{
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("product.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

    writer.WriteComment(Environment.NewLine + "sitemap-generator-url=http://www.auditmypc.com/free-sitemap-generator.asp" + Environment.NewLine);
    writer.WriteComment(Environment.NewLine + " This sitemap was created using the free tool found here: http://www.auditmypc.com/free-sitemap-generator.asp" + Environment.NewLine);
    writer.WriteComment(Environment.NewLine + "Audit My PC also offers free security tools to help keep you safe during internet travels");

    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    writer.Indentation = 2;
    writer.WriteStartElement("urlset");
    createNode("1",  writer);
    createNode("2",  writer);
    createNode("3",  writer);
    createNode("4",  writer);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
    writer.Close();

}
private void createNode(string link,  XmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("url");
    writer.WriteStartElement("loc");
    writer.WriteString(link);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

<!-- sitemap-generator-url=http://www.auditmypc.com/free-sitemap-generator.asp -->

<!-- This sitemap was created using the free tool found here: http://www.auditmypc.com/free-sitemap-generator.asp -->

<!-- Audit My PC also offers free security tools to help keep you safe during internet travels -->
-<urlset> -<url> <loc>http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/India</loc> </url> -<url> <loc>http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/Germany</loc> </url> -<url> <loc>http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/Danmark</loc> </url> -<url> <loc>http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/Spain</loc> </url> </urlset>
```

Comment: please show us the expected output

Answer (score 0):

To use iteration, you can do something like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  List<string> crawledUrls = new List<string>();  // List of  included URLS in c#
  crawledUrls.Add("http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/India");
  crawledUrls.Add("http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/UK");

  string comment = @"sitemap-generator-url=http://www.auditmypc.com/free-sitemap-generator.asp" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine+
                              "This sitemap was created using the free tool found here: http://www.auditmypc.com/free-sitemap-generator.asp" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine+
                              "Audit My PC also offers free security tools to help keep you safe during internet travels";
   XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

    XElement root = new XElement("urlset",
                        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"),
                        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName),
                        new XComment(comment));
        List<XElement> ChildNodes = new List<XElement>();

        foreach(string url in crawledUrls)
        {
            ChildNodes.Add(CreateXMLNode(url));
        }
        root.Add(ChildNodes);

        root.Save("d:/product.xml");
    }

    public static XElement CreateXMLNode(string url)
    {
        XElement urlnode = new XElement("url");
        urlnode.Add(new XElement("loc",url));
        return urlnode;
    }
```